# How to Create 'Remember Me' using jquery , store cookies

Tags: cookies

How to Create 'Remember Me' using Javascript , store cookies

any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at tutorials that are out there, such as http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

> "On this page I give three functions
>   to save, read and erase cookies. Using
>   these functions you can manage cookies
>   on your site."

Comment: What about the *remember me*?